# Performance optimisation of Cucumber TestNG tests

Tags: java, multithreading, cucumber, testng

I have setup automation framework with Cucumber and TestNg for my backend tests having multiple scenarios with each scenarios set with around 600 examples which is leading to around 25k+ tests.
As the number of tests are huge, I would like to run the tests concurrently and reduce execution time.

In order to achieve this, I used data provider thread count for scenarios to execute concurrently and let's assume 20.
I observed that from the number of threads which got created, only few will be running at any point of time and others will be in waiting state as this is based on thread scheduler in java.
Even with this approach still the execution time is too long which again requires optimisation.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps you are running into limitations of the hardware itself? Then your will need to really split up the tests, not just into threads but into different tasks. Then run each task on a different test runner machine.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Jorn Can you please help me with an article to follow for executing different tasks on different test runner machines. Currently, I have test runners for each feature file and is executed concurrently as provisioned in TestNG to provide parallel="classes" attribute and along with that the scenarios within the feature files are also executed synchronously using dataprovider option in runner class. If I can delegate these tests to different machines that would help to bring multiple threads to run at any point. I am also figuring out forking through maven to bring jvm's for each runner class.